# group_by and lag not working for date in long format

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I have a long historical data like this format (unbalanced). While there is a lag until the data is released (next business day), I would like to record the date as of the day it happened. I tried to use dplyr as follows:

```
dataframe<-dataframe%>%group_by(date)%>%mutate(cob=lag(date,n=1))
```

However, it just produces the same result as:

```
lag(date,1)
```

| date | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023/1/2 | a | X |
| 2023/1/2 | b | X |
| 2023/1/2 | c | X |
| 2023/1/3 | a | X |
| 2023/1/3 | b | X |
| 2023/1/4 | a | X |
| 2023/1/4 | b | X |
| 2023/1/5 | a | X |
| 2023/1/5 | b | X |
| 2023/1/5 | c | X |

I thought about:

```
dataframe<-dataframe%>%group_by(name)%>%mutate(cob=lag(date,n=1))
```

but it produces NA when there is no observation for a certain sample.
`mutate(cob=date-1)`
is not considering business day.

I just would like to slide all the dates in dataframe$date by 1 business day.

I attached the part of the actual data (historical prices of Japanese treasury bills).

```
structure(list(date = c("2002-08-06", "2002-08-06", "2002-08-07", 
"2002-08-07", "2002-08-09", "2002-08-09"), code = c(2870075L, 
3000075L, 2870075L, 3000075L, 2870075L, 3000075L), due_date = c("2002-08-20", 
"2002-09-10", "2002-08-20", "2002-09-10", "2002-08-20", "2002-09-10"
), ave_price = c(99.99, 99.99, 99.99, 99.99, 99.99, 99.99)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
    date = c("2002-08-06", "2002-08-07", "2002-08-09"), .rows = structure(list(
        1:2, 3:4, 5:6), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))
```

The expected outcome is as follows:

```
structure(list(date = c("2002-08-06", "2002-08-06", "2002-08-07", 
"2002-08-07", "2002-08-09", "2002-08-09"), code = c(2870075L, 
3000075L, 2870075L, 3000075L, 2870075L, 3000075L), due_date = c("2002-08-20", 
"2002-09-10", "2002-08-20", "2002-09-10", "2002-08-20", "2002-09-10"
), ave_price = c(99.99, 99.99, 99.99, 99.99, 99.99, 99.99), cob = c(NA, 
NA, "2002-08-06", "2002-08-06", "2002-08-07", "2002-08-07")), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
    date = c("2002-08-06", "2002-08-07", "2002-08-09"), .rows = structure(list(
        1:2, 3:4, 5:6), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try with `dplyr::mutate(cob = dplyr::lag(date, n =1))`

Comment: `lag(date, n=1)` will knowingly produce `NA` for the first observation within each group of `name`, since there are no previous observations within the group. If you want to change that from `NA` to something else (e.g., `first(date)-1` or just `first(date)`), then use `default=` (which accepts a length-1 vector aka a scalar).

Comment: If the problem is that your code is unintentionally using `stats::lag`, then akrun's comment of using `dplyr::lag` explicitly should resolve the problem. If it is something else, please share `dput(head(dataframe,10))`, and please be explicit (perhaps within that sample) what your code is producing and what it should be (i.e., expected output).

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, but I am still facing the problem. I managed to extract a part of the actual data and added it to the main text. Could you please take a look at it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the previous date recorded in your `date` column as `cob`. So, your Aug 9 rows would have the previously recorded date of Aug 7 in your `cob` column.

If so, you could try the following. First, your example data above is grouped so I started with `ungroup`. You can get a vector of unique or `distinct` dates, and get the `lag` or previous date for those dates. In this case, dates of Aug 6, 7, and 9 will have `cob` set as NA, Aug 6, and Aug 7.

Then, you can join back to original data with `right_join`. The final `select` will keep columns and include order desired.

I left `date` alone (currently is character value, not in date format).

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  distinct(date) %>%
  mutate(cob = lag(date)) %>%
  right_join(df) %>%
  select(date, code, due_date, ave_price, cob)
```

**Output**

```
  date          code due_date   ave_price cob       
  <chr>        <int> <chr>          <dbl> <chr>     
1 2002-08-06 2870075 2002-08-20      100. NA        
2 2002-08-06 3000075 2002-09-10      100. NA        
3 2002-08-07 2870075 2002-08-20      100. 2002-08-06
4 2002-08-07 3000075 2002-09-10      100. 2002-08-06
5 2002-08-09 2870075 2002-08-20      100. 2002-08-07
6 2002-08-09 3000075 2002-09-10      100. 2002-08-07
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I couldn't think up using right_join in this way by myself and this results in precisely what I wanted!